# validate CSV files in Grunt build

Tags: csv, gruntjs, lint

How can I validate CSV files (encoding, headline, delimiter, column count) in my Grunt build? I had a look at [CSVLint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvlint) but neither get it to work, nor know how to include it in Grunt.

Edit: [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com) looks promising, but has no Grunt integration either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although grunt integration for [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/) does not exist its API can be utilized by configuring a custom [Function Task](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask) inside your `Gruntfile.js`.

---

**Install papaparse via npm**

Firstly, `cd` to your project directory, install [papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse) via npm and add it to the `devDependencies` section of your projects `package.json`. To do this run the following command via your CLI tool:

`$ npm i -D papaparse`

---

**Gruntfile.js**

The following gist shows how to configure a custom Function Task named `validateCSV` in your `Gruntfile.js`.

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Requirements
    var fs = require('fs');
    var Papa = require('papaparse');

    // Other project configuration tasks.
    grunt.initConfig({
        // ...
    });

    /**
     * Register a custom Function task to validate .csv files using Papa Parse.
     */
    grunt.registerTask('validateCSV', 'Lint .csv files via Papa Parse', function() {

        var glob = './csv/*.csv'; // <-- Note: Edit glob pattern as required.

        var success = true;

        // Create an Array of all .csv files using the glob pattern provided.
        var csvFiles = grunt.file.expand(glob).map(function(file) {
            return file;
        });

        // Report if no .csv files were found and return early.
        if (csvFiles.length === 0) {
            grunt.log.write('No .csv files were found');
            return;
        }

        // Loop over each .csv file in the csvFiles Array.
        csvFiles.forEach(function(csvFile) {

            // Read the contents of the .csv file.
            var csvString = fs.readFileSync(csvFile, {
                encoding: 'utf8'
            });

            // Parse the .csv contents via Papa Parse.
            var papa = Papa.parse(csvString, {
                delimiter: ',',
                newline: '',
                quoteChar: '"',
                header: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true

                // For additional config options visit:
                // http://papaparse.com/docs#config
            });

            // Basic error and success logging.
            if (papa.errors.length > 0) {
                grunt.log.error('Error(s) in file: '['red'] + csvFile['red']);

                // Report each error for a single .csv file.
                // For additional Papa Parse errors visit:
                // http://papaparse.com/docs#errors
                papa.errors.forEach(function(error) {
                    grunt.log.write('\n   type: ' + error.type);
                    grunt.log.write('\n   code: ' + error.code);
                    grunt.log.write('\n   message: ' + error.message);
                    grunt.log.write('\n   row: ' + error.row + '\n\n');
                });

                // Indicate that a .csv file failed validation.
                success = false;

            } else {
                grunt.log.ok('No errors found in file: ' + csvFile);
            }
        });

        // If errors are found in any of the .csv files this will
        // prevent subsequent defined tasks from being processed.
        if (!success) {
            grunt.fail.warn('Errors(s) were found when validating .csv files');
        }
    });

    // Register the custom Function task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'validateCSV'
        // ...
    ]);

};
```

**Notes**

The following line of code (taken from the `Gruntfile.js` above) that reads:

```js
var glob = './csv/*.csv';
```

... will need to be changed/edited according to your project requirements. Currently the [globbing pattern](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) assumes all `.csv` files reside inside a folder named `csv`.

You *may* also need to set the [config](http://papaparse.com/docs#config) options as per your requirements.

The custom Function Task also includes some basic error and success reporting that will be logged to the CLI.

---

**Running the Task**

To run the grunt task simply execute the following via your CLI tool:

`$ grunt validateCSV`

---

**EDIT: Updated Answer** *(based on the following comment...)*

> Would it also be possible to "configure" the task from within the
>   `grunt.initConfig()`? For example linting different CSV directories?

To achieve this you can create a separate Javascript module that exports a [Registered MutliTask](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registermultitask).

Lets call it `papaparse.js` and save it to a directory named `custom-grunt-tasks` which resides in the same top level directory as your `Gruntfile.js`

*Note: This `.js` file and directory name can be any name that you prefer, however you will need to updated the references inside `Gruntfile.js`.*

**papaparse.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    'use strict';

    // Requirements
    var fs = require('fs');
    var Papa = require('papaparse');

    grunt.registerMultiTask('papaparse', 'Misc Tasks', function() {

        // Default options. These are used when no options are
        // provided via the  initConfig({...}) papaparse task.
        var options = this.options({
            quotes: false,
            delimiter: ',',
            newline: '',
            quoteChar: '"',
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true
        });

        // Loop over each path provided via the src array.
        this.data.src.forEach(function(dir) {

            // Append a forward slash If a directory path
            // provided does not end in with one.
            if (dir.slice(-1) !== '/') {
                dir += '/';
            }

            // Generate the globbin pattern.
            var glob = [dir, '*.csv'].join('');

            // Create an Array of all .csv files using the glob pattern.
            var csvFiles = grunt.file.expand(glob).map(function(file) {
                return file;
            });

            // Report if no .csv files were found and return early.
            if (csvFiles.length === 0) {
                grunt.log.write(
                    '>> No .csv files found using the globbing '['yellow'] +
                    'pattern: '['yellow'] + glob['yellow']
                );
                return;
            }

            // Loop over each .csv file in the csvFiles Array.
            csvFiles.forEach(function(csvFile) {

                var success = true;

                // Read the contents of the .csv file.
                var csvString = fs.readFileSync(csvFile, {
                    encoding: 'utf8'
                });

                // Parse the .csv contents via Papa Parse.
                var papa = Papa.parse(csvString, options);

                // Basic error and success logging.
                if (papa.errors.length > 0) {
                    grunt.log.error('Error(s) in file: '['red'] + csvFile['red']);

                    // Report each error for a single .csv file.
                    // For additional Papa Parse errors visit:
                    // http://papaparse.com/docs#errors
                    papa.errors.forEach(function(error) {
                        grunt.log.write('\n   type: ' + error.type);
                        grunt.log.write('\n   code: ' + error.code);
                        grunt.log.write('\n   message: ' + error.message);
                        grunt.log.write('\n   row: ' + error.row + '\n\n');
                    });

                    // Indicate that a .csv file failed validation.
                    success = false;

                } else {
                    grunt.log.ok('No errors found in file: ' + csvFile);
                }

                // If errors are found in any of the .csv files this will prevent
                // subsequent files and defined tasks from being processed.
                if (!success) {
                    grunt.fail.warn('Errors(s) found when validating .csv files');
                }
            });

        });
    });
};
```

**Gruntfile.js**

Your `Gruntfile.js` can then be configured something like this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        // ...
        papaparse: {
            setOne: {
                src: ['./csv/', './csv2']
            },
            setTwo: {
                src: ['./csv3/'],
                options: {
                    skipEmptyLines: false
                }
            }
        }

    });

    // Load the custom multiTask named `papaparse` - which is defined in
    // `papaparse.js` stored in the directory named `custom-grunt-tasks`.
    grunt.loadTasks('./custom-grunt-tasks');

    // Register and add papaparse to the default Task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'papaparse' // <-- This runs Targets named setOne and setTwo
        // ...
    ]);

    // `papaparse.js` allows for multiple targets to be defined, so
    // you can use the colon notation to just run one Target.
    // The following only runs the setTwo Target.
    grunt.registerTask('processOneTarget', [
        'papaparse:setTwo'
        // ...
    ]);

};
```

**Running the Task**

The `papaparse` Task has been added to the `taskList` Array of the `default` Task, so it can be executed by entering the following via your CLI tool:

$ grunt

**Notes**

1. Running the example gist by entering `$ grunt` via your CLI will process all `.csv` files inside the directories named `csv`, `csv2`, and `csv3`.
2. Running `$ grunt processOneTarget` via your CLI will process only `.csv` files inside the directory named `csv3`.
3. As the `papaparse.js` utilizes a `MultiTask` you'll notice that in the `papaparse` Task defined in `Gruntfile.js` it includes two Targets. Namely `setOne` and `setTwo`.
4. The `setOne` Target `src` Array defines paths to two directories that should be processed. I.e. Directories `./csv/` and `./csv2`. All `.csv` files found in these paths will be processed using the default `papaparse` options defined in `papaparse.js` as the Target does not define any custom `options`.
5. The `setTwo` target `src` Array defines a path to one directory. (I.e. `./csv3/`). All `.csv` files found in this path will be processed using the default `papaparse` options defined in `papaparse.js` with the exception of the `skipEmptyLines` option as it's set to `false`.
6. You may find that simply defining one Target in `Gruntfile.js` with multiple paths in the `src` Array, without any custom options, meets your requirement. For Example:

```js
// ...
    grunt.initConfig({
        // ...
        papaparse: {
            myTask: {
                src: ['./csv/', './csv2', './csv3']
            }
        }
        // ...
    });
// ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thank you. Would it also be possible to "configure" the task from within the grunt.initConfig()? For example linting different CSV directories?

Comment: **Updated Answer:** Looks like there is a way to configure it via `grunt.initConfig()` - Refer to the revised  _"EDIT: Updated Answer"_ section of my original answer.